# declaring some value to ng-app is not working

Tags: angularjs

i am new to angularjs and i tried practicing some examples. the below stated example is working fine if i dont declare any value to ng-app. But the same is not working as intended if i declare ng-app any value (ng-app="myapp"). Please kindly anyone let me know the reason why if i declare something to ng-app demo is not working.

```
<head>
    <title>My Practices</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" placeholder="enter your name">
    <div>Hi {{value}} !! </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ng-app must match the name of your main module, which you declare like

`angular.module('myapp', [])`

if you're still having problems show your JS, and ideally a plnkr.co link or running code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation shaun. yeah i missed to define  myapp. it is working now